# Upgrading iPhone App

Tags: iphone, new-operator

I currently have the first version (1.x.x) of my iPhone app on the App Store. I've updated it before, and it has never been a problem. However, I am about to update it to version 2, and because I re-wrote it from the ground up, I started it in a new Xcode project.

Version 2 works great on my phone, but when I download version 1 from the App Store, and then install Version 2 on top of that, it crashes immediately on launch. I literally mean immediately, the phone never goes away from Springboard.

I've done a little digging, and someone suggested trying it in the iPhone Simulator. It actually does work fine in the Simulator. I just want to be 100% sure that this won't be an issue for people upgrading.

Has anyone had this problem before? And if so was it fine when you published it to the App Store?

Thanks!

Comment: Connect device to the desktop. Install version 1.X. Install and run version 2.X from XCode. What do you see in the console?

Comment: The simulator, as its name suggests, should be simulating what a real iPhone would do. If it's behaving differently, make sure you aren't behaving differently. Are you installing Version 2 on the simulator the same way you are on the real iPhone?

Comment: I have connected it to my computer and nothing appears in the console. It just says "finished running" at the top of Xcode. It's like it never runs at all. Also the app does not use Core Data. Both versions use the same version of SQLite 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to follow up, once it was approved and available on the App Store, it was able to install just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using CoreData? If you do not use some sort of version control on your data model, and have changed it since version 1, your app will crash. The best thing to do is copy the old model into your new project and create a new version. This will help CoreData migrate information from the old data model into the new one.